# will mysqli->rollback(), rollback every query that has been previously committed?

Tags: php, transactions, mysqli, commit, rollback

I want to know if mysqli->rollback will rollback all the queries that have been committed before the rollback.

For example, in the code below, the first query will be committed, but the second query will fail because of misspelling 'username'. Does that mean that the query before the rollback will or will not get executed?

```
$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);

$query = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('user123', '1apple')";
$query2 = "INSERT INTO users (**usernam**, password) VALUES ('user987', '2apple')";

if($resrouce = $mysqli->query($query)){

    $mysqli->commit();

    if($resource2 = $mysqli->query($query2)){

        $mysqli->commit();

    }else{

        $mysqli->rollback();

    }

}else{
    $mysqli->rollback();
}
```

Comment: Rollback only rolls back statements that have not yet been committed...

Answer (score 4):

Once you commit the transaction , you can not rollback it , you can only rollback the statement which is not comited yet

Comment: Well, you can perform [point-in-time recovery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/point-in-time-recovery.html)... but you're right, this isn't really "rollback" in the true sense of the word.

Answer (score 1):

modify line 8 and add a line in the end in your code:

```
$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);

$query = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('user123', '1apple')";
$query2 = "INSERT INTO users (**usernam**, password) VALUES ('user987', '2apple')";

if($resrouce = $mysqli->query($query)){

    //$mysqli->commit(); this not necesary

    if($resource2 = $mysqli->query($query2)){

        $mysqli->commit();

    }else{

        $mysqli->rollback();

    }

}else{
    $mysqli->rollback();
}

$mysqli->close();
```

Answer (score -3):

Personally I find the PDO library better for database access than mysqli. You can check:
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php

which does exactly what you need... Hope that helps

Comment: In what way does PDO enable one to rollback committed transactions?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php
First two lines of the manual ... ?

Comment: Ah, the manual is unfortunately ambiguous.  The second sentence "*changes made to the database via the PDO object instance are not committed until you end the transaction by calling PDO::commit()*" is key; the third sentence "*Calling PDO::rollBack() will roll back all changes to the database and return the connection to autocommit mode.*" should be more clear that only uncommitted changes/changes made in the current transaction will be rolled back.

Comment: I am pretty sure if you wrap the whole thing in a try catch block and rollback if the commit throws an error it should roll back the whole thing. Otherwise whats the point of using a transaction to begin with if you cannot roll back the state...

Comment: Sure, if the commit *fails* then obviously any updates will not have been committed and a rollback will restore the database to the pre-transaction state.  But once a commit has succeeded, the transaction is over and can no longer be rolled back.